# CHMOD Permissions for folders

Tags: file-permissions

I seem to have a problem when trying to set permissions for my files since I try to set some permissions for my folders on the server.

I've tried setting the permissions to 666 but I can still be able to view the files in the directory I access to. When I check the permission again, it says it's 766.

I have some folders that some of my scripts copy files to, so what chmod number will I need in order for some files to be copied/written to without showing the files to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

700 on a directory will allow you read/write access for yourself, and no access for group or other.

750 will allow full access for yourself, read-only access for the group, and no access for others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-R` with `chmod` command to change the permissions of the files inside a folder.

The appropriate mode of the folders for your script depends on the user that is running your script. If you are running the script as `root`, the following permissions will enable full access to your script and nothing to all other users.

```
Owner: root
Group: root
Mod: 700
```

Answer (score 0):

Not meant offensive, but this helps me all the time to calculate ownerships:

```
user  group  others
rwx   rwx    rwx
421   421    421     = 0777 # the zero is for SUID, SGID and sticky bit

user  group  others
rwx   r-x    ---
421   401    000     = 0750 # the zero is for SUID, SGID and sticky bit
```

Comment: You could look into symbolic notation if you have a hard time remembering the numerical values.